# How to inherit react SectionList prop type in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-props

I am creating a wrapper around [SectionList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist), which should take all props that SectionList takes, plus my custom props. How can I configure typescript for that?

Here's my attempt:

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, SectionList } from 'react-native';

interface EnhancedSectionListProps {
  ...SectionListProps;   // this obviously won't compile, but shows what I'm trying to achieve
  enhancedProp: string;
}

export const EnhancedSectionList = (props: EnhancedSectionListProps) => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <SectionList {...props} />
      // use my `enhancedProp` here
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

PS: We are **not** using the `prop-types` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish the task, you will need to **extend** the interface. For example:

```
interface EnhancedSectionListProps extends SectionListProps {
  enhancedProp: string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, being a Java dev, I should have tried this. I had to use `SectionListProps<any>`, would you know what generic type it expects?

Comment: I think SectionListProps has a mechanism of extending the default props. Sometimes, in place of ````any````, you can pass an interface to extend it by that interface. So, can you check whether ````SectionListProps<{enhancedProp: string}>```` works in place of ````EnhancedSectionListProps````? However, I can be wrong. This actually depends on how the ````SectionListProps```` is implemented.